# Get the character typed by the user

Tags: dom, dart, user-input, dom-events, keyboard-events

I want to process the characters typed by the user for a game (I don't want to use an input tag with a submit button).

I managed to get the keyCode typed with this code:

```
window.on.keyPress.add((Event e) 
{
    window.alert('${e.keyCode},${e.keyIdentifier},${e.charCode}');

});
```

but I don't know how to display the character of the key pressed (or even get the character of the key as a string).
In Javascript there is a `fromKeyCode()` function but not in Dart.

Anyway, I am looking for the simplest way to get the keyboard inputs for processing and I would prefer not have to fiddle with keycodes and such.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/global-dart-hackathon/9_Sx336By1g does this help?

Comment: I have already read this post and others like that. The problem is that I should then associate all the characters with their codes but since the keypress value change between browsers it is not a good idea, and the keycode value while not changing doesn't recognize the case.
I need a way to let the user enter words and enter them, this is as simple as that, but since it is for a text game I can't use input tags and the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a new string from the character code with [String.fromCharCodes()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_core/String.html#String.fromCharCodes).

```
var str = new String.fromCharCodes([e.charCode]);
```

However it's certainly not the most efficient to be creating a new string each time a user hits a key depending on your game. If you only expect a few specific characters to be hit and ignore others then you may want to create constant/final variables of character codes to compare the character code from the event.

```
final E_KEY = "e".charCodeAt(0);
// ... etc.
```

Keep in mind these don't account for various situations such a capitalization, or the CTRL or ALT or meta key pressed, etc.

Comment: I've managed to do a basic typed character recognition with this code :

  `document.on.keyPress.add((KeyboardEvent event) {
      final String char = new String.fromCharCodes([event.charCode]);
      window.alert('Key: $char');
   });`

I may use the charCodeAt(0) attribute if needed later thanks ^^

Answer (score 3):

`String.fromCharCodes()` is gone

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

String result = UTF8.decode([e.charCode]); // or [e.keyCode]
```

Comment: Works for me with keyCode instead of charCode: UTF8.decode([e.keyCode])

Answer (score 2):

[String.fromCharCodes](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.String#id_String-fromCharCodes) seems to work fine with recent Dart SDKs.

Just confirmed with v1.9.1_r44672:

```
String result = new String.fromCharCodes([event.charCode]);
```

If only one character needs to be converted to the corresponding String representation, [String.fromCharCode (singular)](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.String#id_String-fromCharCode) can be used instead.